# restarting AsyncTask in Service

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I have Service and AsyncTask in it, which due to check updatings on the server. It have to be reexecuted if it get some data and also if it doesn't. So my AsyncTask implementation is :

```
 private class DklabExecute extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
            int count;

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
             java.util.Date now = calendar.getTime();
             java.sql.Timestamp currentTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(now.getTime());
            String url = "http://192.168.0.250:81/?identifier=nspid_"+md5(LoginActivity.passUserId)+
                      ",nspc&ncrnd="+Long.toString(currentTimestamp.getTime());

            HttpGet rplPost = new HttpGet(url);

            protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) 
            {

                Log.i("service count", Integer.toString(count));
                count ++;
             Log.i("md5 func", md5(LoginActivity.passUserId)); 


                String testData = "http://192.168.0.250/app_dev.php/api/comet/testOrder/";

                 JSONParser  parser = new JSONParser();
                 DefaultHttpClient testClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 DefaultHttpClient rplClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                try {

                     List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("", ""));
                     HttpGet httpTest = new HttpGet(testData);

                     httpTest.setHeader("Cookie", CookieStorage.getInstance().getArrayList().get(0).toString());
                     rplPost.setHeader("Cookie", CookieStorage.getInstance().getArrayList().get(0).toString());

                    try {



                        httpResponse = rplClient.execute(rplPost);
                    }

                     catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Header[] head = httpResponse.getAllHeaders();
                    Log.i("http Response",httpResponse.toString());
                    for (Header one:head)
                    {
                        Log.i("headers",one.toString());
                    }
                    Log.i("response code", Integer.toString(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()));
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            sb.append(line);// + "n");
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            is.close();
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    json = sb.toString();
                    Log.i("rpl response",json);
                    if (new JSONArray(json) != null)
                        jArr = new JSONArray(json);
                    else
                        this.cancel(true);
                     JSONObject toObj = jArr.getJSONObject(0);
                     JSONObject data = toObj.getJSONObject(KEY_DATA);
                    if (data.has(KEY_ORDER))
                    {
                        for (Order a : ServiceMessages.orderExport)
                          {
                             Log.i("service before list", a.toString());
                          }
                         Log.i(" ", "  ");
                          for (Order a : DashboardActivityAlt.forPrint)
                          {

                             Log.i("before dashboard list", a.toString());
                          }
                        JSONObject jsonOrder = data.getJSONObject(KEY_ORDER);
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Order orderObj= gson.fromJson(jsonOrder.toString(), Order.class);
                        try
                        {
                            for (ListIterator<Order> itr = orderExport.listIterator(); itr.hasNext();)
                            {
                                Order a = itr.next();

                                Log.i("order count", a.toString());

                                if(orderObj.getOrderid()==a.getOrderid())
                                {
                                    Log.i("Service","order was changed");
                                    a = orderObj;
                                    someMethod("Your order  "+ orderObj.getTitle() + "  was changed");

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Log.i("Service","order"+ orderObj.getTitle()+" was added");
    //                              DashboardActivityAlt.forPrint.add(0, orderObj);
                                    ServiceMessages.orderExport.add(0,orderObj);
                                    Log.i("status",Integer.toString(orderObj.getProcess_status().getProccessStatusId()));
                                    someMethod("Your order  "+ orderObj.getTitle() + "  was added");
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        for (Order a : ServiceMessages.orderExport)
                          {

                             Log.i("service after list", a.toString());
                          }
                         Log.i(" ", "  ");
                          for (Order a : DashboardActivityAlt.forPrint)
                          {

                             Log.i("after dashboard list", a.toString());
                          }
//                      intentOrder.putParcelableArrayListExtra("ordersService", orderExport);
                        sendBroadcast(intentOrder);
                        Log.i("after parse order",orderObj.toString());
                        Log.i("orders after updating",DashboardActivityAlt.orders.toString() );
                    }
                    else if (data.has(KEY_MESSAGE))
                    {

                        JSONObject jsonMessage = data.getJSONObject(KEY_MESSAGE);
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Log.i("messages before parse", jsonMessage.toString());
                        for (Order a: DashboardActivityAlt.forPrint)
                        {
                            Log.i("messages count", Integer.toString(a.getCusThread().getMessages().size()));
                        }
                        Log.i("disparse message",jsonMessage.toString());
                        Message message =  gson.fromJson(jsonMessage.toString(),Message.class);
                        Log.i("incomming message",message.toString());
                        JSONObject jsonThread = jsonMessage.getJSONObject(KEY_THREAD);
                        Threads thread =  gson.fromJson(jsonThread.toString(),Threads.class);
                        Log.i("incomming thread",thread.toString());
                        Order orderChanged = new Order();
                        String orderName = null;
                        for(Order as : DashboardActivityAlt.forPrint)
                        {

                            if (as.getOrderid() == thread.getTreadOrder().getOrderid())
                            {
                                orderName = as.getTitle();
                                orderChanged = as;
                                Log.i("messages count after", Integer.toString(as.getCusThread().getMessages().size()));
                            }

                        }
                        Log.i("orderchanged",orderChanged.toString());
                        someMethod("Your order  "+ thread.getTreadOrder().getTitle() + "  was changed. Message was added");
                        orderChanged.getCusThread().addMessage(message);
                        sendBroadcast(intentMessage);
                        Log.i("messages service", "before sleep");

                        Log.i("messages service", "after sleep");

                    }
                    else

                    {

                        this.cancel(true);

                    }

                } 
                 catch (IllegalStateException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                     rplClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                     testClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                     someMethod("You've lost internet connection. You should try later.");
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

                return null;
             }
            protected void onPostExecute(Void bitmap) {

                 this.cancel(true);
                 new DklabExecute().execute();
             }
        }
```

If I send some data to the server, it gives me back in JSON format via rpl server. Everything works good, but the problem is when I get some data from the server, AsyncTask reexecuted in `onPostExecute()` method and it is the same reapeted one or two times data in my list of orders. If I do not reexecute AsyncTask the listening happens only in `onStartCommand()` method but not permanently. Tell me please how can I implement this in the best manner...

Comment: Why do you use an AsyncTask in a Service? You can normally do "network" stuff on a service without the need of an AsyncTask

Comment: i don't understand the problem, and the code is too long. (aren't you supposed to start an async task at regular intervals to perform your polling ? if so, use an alarm manager)

Comment: Because Service do not use different thread, but executing in the UI thread. And I have web request and parsing response data which as I guess have to execute in differ from UI thread. And also I want to supply permanent listening for thge new data from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's a service there's no reason to use an AsyncTask.
AyncTasks were build to deliver content back on the original thread (normally a UI thread), but services don't have those.

I suggest you use a ScheduledExecutorService instead http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

```
 private ScheduledExecutorService executor;

 // call those on startCommand
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(run, 250,3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

and have a Runnable doing the work

```
private Runnable run = new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
              // do your network stuff
      }
};
```

and don't forget to cancel everything when your service stops

```
   executor.shutdown();
```

### *edit:*

or to use a thread in loop you can:

```
    boolean isRunning;
```

.

```
    // this on your start
    Thread t = new Thread(run);
    isRunning = true;
    t.start();
```

the runnable

```
private Runnable run = new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
              while(isRunning){
                    // do your network stuff
              }
      }
};
```

and again, don't forget to finish it whenever the service finishes with:

```
     isRunning = false;
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but I want to have permanent listening to the server, not with the delay...

Comment: there're two options: 1) put a very small delay 10ms for example. 2) Just use a Thread (i'll update my question with it)

Comment: but what is the difference between Thread approach and AsyncTask? and where should I do isRunning = false;

Comment: `isRunning = false` is whenever you want to stop your service, or in your service onDestroy(); But those are very basic concepts that someone that does not fully understand should study more before trying complex stuff such as a service. Remember that this thing executing all the time WILL drain the battery and data connection and that's something you only want to do under very specific circumstances. Be careful there!

Comment: I do not want to stop it, I want it to be running through program lifecycle. I want it to be running, receive some data and be reexecuted...

Comment: so whenever the program stops you want to stop it ;)

Comment: yes, thank you...it works faster with the Thread approach. Thank you for your suggestions.